# Is it safe to clone an Eclipse CDT .cproject file?

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I've noticed that many attributes in an Eclipse CDT project files (.cproject) contain random numbers, e.g.

> cconfiguration id="ilg.gnuarmeclipse.managedbuild.cross.config.elf.debug.**980615563**"

So:

- What are they for?
- Is it safe to clone such a project, and include it in the same workspace as the original (after renaming it, of course)?

Comment: Projects can be safely cloned by copying and pasting them in the Project Explorer. I would not suggest trying to clone one manually by copying the folder in the filesystem.